# Why are Borel functions measurable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $f: M\to N$ be a map between topological spaces, equipped with their Borel algebras (smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets).

- $f$ is *measurable* if for $U\subset N$ measurable, $f^{-1}(U)$ measurable.
- $f$ is a *Borel function* if for $U\subset N$ open, $f^{-1}(U)$ measurable.

Why does the second imply the first?

My attempt at proving this has come to showing that if $f$ measurably pulls back a generating set for the codomain's $\sigma$-algebra, it measurable pulls back the entire $\sigma$-algebra. I don't know how to prove this claim for $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: The collection of all Borel sets $U$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is  Borel set is a sigma algebra containing all open sets. so it contains all Borel sets.

Comment: I see. Thank you.